# Update statement is not working with abstracting attributes

Tags: php, mysql

My code looks fine but it is not working as it should because update statement is working. When I call this function my page loads without showing any errors on my screen.

```
    public function update(){
        global $database;
        $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
        $attributes_pairs = array();
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
            $attributes_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE ".static::$table_name." SET ";
        $sql .= join(", ", $attributes_pairs);
        $sql .= " WHERE id=".static::$i_d;
        $database->query($sql);
        return ($database->affected_rows() == 1)? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Are there any rows to be updated? If the matched rows already contain the new values, they won't be modified and `affected_rows` will be 0.

Comment: Is this new code you are working on?

Comment: What happens if you printing the query and execute it in PhpMyAdmin or something similar? Btw, the code looks hirrible with 'global' and 'static::$i_d'.

Comment: I am getting only id attribute not others.
    $attributes array contains only id attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code doesn't look ok to me, the update with join is first JOIN and then SET, take a look to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

or

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.COLUMN_1= TABLE_2.COLUMN_2
SET TABLE_1.COLUMN = EXPR WHERE TABLE_2.COLUMN2 IS NULL
```

In your case try to make join first and then try the "set" statement